# javascript calculator not working properly

Tags: javascript, calculator

hi so i am new to javascript and i am trying to make a simple calculator using HTML and js. However i have run into a problem where i press the button to calculate the answer and it wont do anything. I tried it in an online ide and it just gave me the wrong answer. here is the code can anyone help. thanks--

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>calculator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("equals").onclick = function() {
        var answer = parseInt(document.getElementById('number_1').value)+ parseInt(document.getElementById('number_1').value);
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = answer;
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
            <input type="text" name="number_1" id = "number_1">
            <p>+</p>
            <input type="text" name="number_2" id = "number_2">
            <input type="submit" name="equals" id = "equals" value="=">
            <p id = "answer"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: debugging your own code is also part of programming

Comment: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the value from the same input twice and you have to set the event handler after the button is created, .

```
<body>
    <input type="text" name="number_1" id = "number_1">
    <p>+</p>
    <input type="text" name="number_2" id = "number_2">
    <input type="submit" name="equals" id = "equals" value="=">
    <p id = "answer"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("equals").onclick = function() {
        var answer = parseInt(document.getElementById('number_1').value)+ parseInt(document.getElementById('number_1').value);
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = answer;
    };
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: ok thanks, but that still does not fix the fact that when i press the button nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

forms including onClick conditions without `GET/POST` methods , generally use `button` .

```
 <input type="button" name="equals" id="equals" value="=">
```

I guess you are adding same variables twice ?

```
var answer = parseInt(document.getElementById('number_1').value)+ parseInt(document.getElementById('number_2').value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you are adding the event click to element equals, but in these moment, element equals doesn't exists.

wrap your document.getElementById into window.onload function to say javascript: "when all the document finish to load, add the event click to element equals"

try this:

```
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("equals").onclick = function() {
            var answer = parseInt(document.getElementById('number_1').value, 10)+ parseInt(document.getElementById('number_2').value, 10);
            document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = answer;
        };
    }
```

Another important thing I have added ,10 to your parseint, this is to make sure that the conversion is to a number into decimal mode

"The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.

The radix parameter is used to specify which numeral system to be used, for example, a radix of 16 (hexadecimal) indicates that the number in the string should be parsed from a hexadecimal number to a decimal number.

If the radix parameter is omitted, JavaScript assumes the following:

If the string begins with "0x", the radix is 16 (hexadecimal)
If the string begins with "0", the radix is 8 (octal). This feature is deprecated
If the string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal)"

Source: [parseInt use](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it now i had to wrap my code in a window.onload

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>calculator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){ 
        document.getElementById("equals").onclick = function() {
            var answer = parseInt(document.getElementById('number_1').value)+ parseInt(document.getElementById('number_2').value);
            document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = answer;
        };
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
            <input type="text" name="number_1" id = "number_1">
            <p>+</p>
            <input type="text" name="number_2" id = "number_2">
            <button id = "equals">=</button>
            <p id = "answer"></p>
</body>
</html>
```